# Is it possible to run a bash/apple script in the background and do something when it receives a keyboard combination?

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

Is this possible?
I do not want to have any interface, but just make it execute a command when you press a key?

The reason for doing this is that my mac is rather slow to launch my applescript app service.
So I want it to load all the system info it needs, and then wait until you press a specific keyboard combination.

Comment: Services (partucularly Automator ones) *are* slow. Have you tried just launching the scripts directly (like with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/))?

Comment: I want it to be portable and not depend on FastScripts, Spark or similar...

Comment: @Lri Your comment is the best answer. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Wasn't the question about listening for keyboard events within scripts? I've already posted a totally canonical answer about apps like FastScripts: [Create global shortcut to run command line applications - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943)

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought, but your program sounds like what a Dashboard widget is intended for.